# how to group values in attribute in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a attribute with around 20 25 values. like

```
Briolette
Baguette
Bullet Cabochon
Cushion
Cushion Cabochon
Emerald Cut
Fancy Cut
Fancy cut Cabochon
Half Moon
Heart Shape
Lotus
Marquise
Oval
Oval Cabochon
Pear Shape
Pear Shape Cabochon
Princess Cut
Round
Round Cabochon
Square
Trillion
Trillion Cabochon
```

I am using aw_layerednavigation extension of magento to display them on frontend. They are coming in a dropdown each with a checkbox.
I need to group them like:

```
o   Combine Oval and Oval Cabochon under Oval
o   Combine Cushion Cabochon under Cushion
o   Combine square and Princess cut, rename: Square/Princess
o   Group the following under “other”: Baguette, briolette, half moon, fancy cut, fancy cut cabochon, bullet cabochon
Group Pear Shape Cabochon under Pear shape
Group Trillion Cabochon under Trillion
Group Round cabochon under round
```

Is this make sence?

Below is the code of layer.phtml from which the atrributes value comes in a dropdown:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav" id="aw-ln-filters">
        <!-- div class="block-title">
            <strong><span><?php //echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
        </div -->
        <div class="block-content toggle-content">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var awLnUpdaterInstance = new awLnUpdater();
            </script>
            <?php if($this->isLayerHasAppliedValue()): ?>
                <span class="aw-ln-clear-all">
                    (<a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php echo $this->__("Clear All");?></a>)
                </span>
            <?php endif;?>
            <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter"">
                <?php //echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?>
            </p>
            <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
                <ul id="aw-ln-filters-container">
                    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getFilterList() as $_filter): ?>
                        <?php if($this->getItemCountByFilter($_filter)): ?>

                            <li>
                                <a  href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $_filter->getTitle() ?></a>
                                <?php /*if ($this->isFilterHasAppliedValues($_filter)):?>
                                    <span class="aw-ln-filter-clear">
                                        (<a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php echo $this->__("Clear");?></a>)
                                    </span>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->renderHelp($_filter); ?>
                                <?php endif;*/?>
                                <?php 

                                     ?>
                                <ul id="<?php echo  ++$i; ?>-unique" class="common-class">
                                    <li>
                                        <dd>
                                            <?php echo $this->renderFilter($_filter); ?>
                                        </dd>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
           <script type="text/javascript">
              decorateDataList('aw-ln-filters-container');
               //decorateDataList('aw-ln-filters');
                awLnUpdaterInstance.init({
                    layerContainerElSelector: ".block-layered-nav",
                    productsContainerElSelectorList: [".category-view", ".results-view", ".category-products", ".category_cms_block"],
                    emptyProductsContainerElSelectorList: [".note-msg"],
                    toolbarContainerElSelectorList: [
                        ".category-view .toolbar",
                        ".results-view .toolbar",
                        ".category-products .toolbar"
                    ],
                    clearAllElSelector: '.aw-ln-clear-all',
                    clearFilterElSelector: '.aw-ln-filter-clear',
                    isAjax: <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->isAjax());?>,
                    overlaySettings: <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->getOverlaySettings());?>,
                    overlayCssClass: 'aw-ln-overlay'
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```